# En un bucle que hace recorrer un puntero que está asignado a un arreglo - ¿cin>>*p++ es igual a cin>>*p; p++;?

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for, punteros

Noté que en el bucle de la DECLARACIÓN 1 ponemos (*p++) y supuestamente esto representa que va a recorrer un elemento del arreglo.

Pero me pongo a pensar que lo lógico sería que si mi puntero está iniciando en la posición [0]; en el bucle de la DECLARACIÓN 1 comenzaría guardándolo en la posición [1] ya que está con (*p++).

Sin embargo la DECLARACIÓN 2 me parece más lógica ya que inicia en [0], guarda en la posición [0] y después recorre.

No sé si me dejé entender, ¿Alguien podría explicarme porque es así? y si es que ¿La DECLARACIÓN 1 con la DECLARACIÓN 2 tienen diferencia?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int arreglo[5];
    int *p;

    p = &arreglo[0];
    
    //¿Tienen diferencia estas 2 declaraciones? 

    //DECLARACIÓN 1
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero para la posicion "<<i<<":"; cin>>*p++;
    }
    
    //DECLARACIÓN 2
    /*for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero para la posicion "<<i<<":"; cin>>*p;
        *p++;
    }*/
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los operadores `++` y `--` se conocen como operador de incremento y decremento respectivamente, son un [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico) de una expresión que suma o resta el valor 1 a una variable; así que estas instrucciones:

```
int a = 0;
a++;
a--;
```

Son equivalentes a:

```
int a = 0;
a = a + 1;
a = a - 1;
```

Los operadores de incremento y decremento tienen la particularidad de que pueden ser usados como prefijo (`++variable`) o como sufijo (`variable++`), la diferencia entre el prefijo y el sufijo reside en cuándo se hace la operación.

En la notación de prefijo la operación se hace antes que en la operación de sufijo:

- `++variable`: Primero incrementa el valor, después lo devuelve.
- `variable++`: Primero devuelve el valor, después lo incrementa.

---

Sabiendo esto, vamos a analizar la instrucción que no entiendes: `*p++;`.

Se están aplicando sobre `p` dos operadores, el operador *contenido del puntero* (`*`) y el operador de *incremento* (`++`) en forma de sufijo, si consultamos la [precedencia de operadores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) comprobamos que `++` precede a `*` por lo que la instrucción se realizará en este orden:

1. Devuelve el valor de `p`.
2. Accede al contenido.
3. Incrementa `p`.

Por lo tanto, *DECLARACIÓN 1* y *DECLARACIÓN 2* son equivalentes, pero con diferente código.

Te recomiendo la lectura de: [*La leyenda del preincremento y el postincremento*](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/).